# In Relax NG compact, how can I define 2 elements that at least one of is required?

Tags: xml, relaxng-compact

I need to write an xml schema (i'm using relax NG to generate an rng...) that requires at least 1 of 2 different elements.  So, if the elements are 'fruit' and 'vegetable', acceptable XML would contain 'fruit', 'vegetable', or both.

```
<fruit>apple</fruit>
<vegetable>broccoli</vegetable>
```

This is what I have so far, but this is fruit or vegetable, and if you pass neither fruit NOR vegetable, it works also...

```
& (element Fruit {
    xsd:string { .. }
| (element Vegatable {
    xsd:string { .. }
})?
```

**Update**
The answer seems correct, but I can't figure out how to integrate this.  When you say I can't use an interleave, do you mean I can do something like this?

```
<meal>
  <drink>Water</drink>
  <meat>Chicken</meat>
  <fruit>Apple</fruit>
  <vegetable>Broccoli</vegetable>
</meal>
```

Where either fruit or vegetable or both is required?

**Update 2**:
Does this look correct?

```
fruit = element fruit { xsd:string }
vegetable = element vegetable { xsd:string }
    
start =
  element Meal {
    element Drink { xsd:string },
    element Meat { xsd:string },
    ((fruit , vegetable?) | (fruit? , vegetable))
  }
```

Comment: What you've got in your second update looks fine, if you are okay with the fact that `drink` and `meat` must appear in *this* order (`drink` first, `meat` second) and then you can have either of `fruit`, `vegetable` or both in any order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Relax NG schema requires at least one `fruit` or one `vegetable` and allows both:

```
start = element foo { (fruit, vegetable?) | (vegetable, fruit?) }
fruit = element fruit { xsd:string }
vegetable = element vegetable { xsd:string }
```

I do not believe you could use the interleave pattern to meet your specification precisely.

I've assumed you want a maximum of one `fruit` and one `vegetable` otherwise `start` could be this `start = element foo { (fruit | vegetable)+ }`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I'm still having trouble figuring out how to integrate your answer into our schema.  I've posted an update in the question, sorry to be so dense, but could you explain how to include the answer you posted where there are other elements around it?